# Freemarker The following has evaluated to null or missing

Tags: java, maven, freemarker

I am getting the below error during the evaluation of the freemarker. However, this error only shows up **only in the builds, not in IDE.**

*{"code":"NoApplicableCode","description":"Error occured processing template freemarkerTest.ftl\nThe following has evaluated to null or missing:\n==> loadJSON*

```
//freemarker function
<#assign keywordsJSON = "${loadJSON('path/to/file/random.json')}">
```

```
//function for creating freemarker function
protected void addUtilityFunctions(String baseURL, Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("loadJSON", parseJSON());
}

private TemplateMethodModelEx parseJSON() {
    return arguments -> loadJSON(arguments.get(0).toString());
}

private String loadJSON(String filePath) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
            File file = fileFinder.findFile(filePath);
            if (file == null) {
                LOGGER.warning("File is outside of data directory");
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "File " + filePath + " is outside of the data directory");
            }
            return parser.parse(new FileReader(file.getPath())).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warning("Failed to parse JSON file " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        LOGGER.warning("Failed to create a JSON object");
        return "Failed to create a JSON object";
    }
```

Comment: Where's `addUtilityFunctions` called? Certainly in some cases it's not called.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but two simplifications: 1. Just write `<#assign keywordsJSON = loadJSON('path/to/file/random.json')>`; you don't want the `"${...}"` thing there. 2. If the argument must be string, implement `TemplateMethodModel` instead of `TemplateMethodModelEx`. (If you implement `TemplateMethodModelEx`, then check if `args(0)` is a `TemplateScalarModel`, and if it is then cast to that, and call `getAsString()`.)

Comment: I am sure that addUtilityFunctions is called because all other functions except "loadJSON" are working and they are all called in the same way, which is a private function and lambda reference. 

I also tried your way of simplifying the expression it did not work but it's more elegant. Thanks for that. But the problem is still there. Do you have any more idea? @ddekany

Comment: You mean you add other values to the `model` inside `addUtilityFunctions`, and they are accessible from the template? And is that the only place where those are added to the model? Because there's no feature that could make FreeMarker report that `loadJSON` is missing, when in fact it's in the `model` at the time the template is called.

Comment: Also I assume the error message that you pasted is reasonably complete. Like it's not `The following has evaluated to null or missing: loadJSON('path/to/file/random.json')`. Because if it's indeed just `loadJSON` that's missing, then it doesn't even matter if the lambda works well and such. There's just no any kind of object there with name `loadJSON`.

Comment: Also, silly question maybe, but are you 100% sure that your build is based on the fresh source code? Like if you change something else that's visible in the output, will it be visible if you run the non-IDE version?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there were different functions for different freemarker templates. I did not put the function to the correct place. All syntax and the function calling is true in the question.